# Export files in alphabetical sequence from Mac Photos app

Tags: photos, filesystem, macos

I have a Sony TV which has a Media player for displaying photos and videos. I want to play a slideshow of my pics from the Photos App on my Mac by exporting them on a USB stick which I can plug into my TV. I want the TV to play the files in the order maintained in the Photos app. So I tried exporting the pics from the photos app using the "Sequence" option. This renames the files like 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg, 3.jpeg, and so on. The problem is that my Sony tv sorts files in Alphabetical order, so the file 10.jpeg comes immediately after 1.jpeg, and not 9.jpeg as expected. Hence I want to export the files with names like A.jpeg, B.jpeg, C.jpeg,...AB.jpeg, AC.jpeg and so on. But I am not sure how to do it.

Alternatively, is there any mac app which can convert files named 1, 2, 3 to A, B, C..?

Comment: give us a sample of the current photo file names

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have around 200 files that I have exported from the Photos App. They are named 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg, 3.jpeg, 4.jpg,...200.jpeg. I want to rename them to A.jpeg, B.jpeg, C.jpeg...AA.jpeg, AB.jpeg, ..., RZ.jpeg.

Comment: so now you need Automator script to do that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Any idea where I can get such a script?

Comment: here are multiple solutions http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

You could do it your self using [Automator](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-mac-os-x/)

or using any of the Renaming apps from App Sore.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but learning Automator would probably take some time :).

Comment: I took the easy route and made a small NodeJS program to do the job :P